# Undefined variable Array Slim Application

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this error that runs fine on one of my servers with php 5.4 I transfered the code to a new server with php 5.5.9 and now I am getting this error:

Details

Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined variable: propertylist
File: /var/www/subdomains/api/index.php
Line: 57
Trace

The code:

```
$app->get("/propertylist/", function () use ($app, $db) {
$app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
$req = $app->request();
$bed = $req->get('bed');
$bath = $req->get('bath');
$city = $req->get('city');
$zip = $req->get('zip');
if($bed ==''){$bed=0;}
if($bath ==''){$bath=0;}
if($zip ==''){
$properties = $db->rets_property_listing_mrmls_resi->limit(2500,0)->where("Bedrooms >= ?", $bed)->where("City LIKE ?", "%$city%")->where("BathsTotal >= ?", $bath);
}else{
$properties = $db->rets_property_listing_mrmls_resi->limit(2500,0)->where("Bedrooms >= ?", $bed)->where("ZipCode LIKE ?", "%$zip%")->where("BathsTotal >= ?", $bath);
}
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $propertylist[] = array(
        "MLSnumber" => $property["MLnumber"],
        "ListPrice" => number_format($property["ListPrice"]),
        "StreetNumber" => $property["StreetNumber"],
        "StreetName" => $property["StreetName"],
        "SqFt" => $property["SquareFootageStructure"],
        "PropertyDescription" => summaryMode($property["PropertyDescription"],15),
        "Bedrooms" => $property["Bedrooms"],
        "BathsTotal" => $property["BathsTotal"],
        "LO_Name" => $property["LO_Name"]
        );
}
echo json_encode($propertylist);
});
```

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create/define variable before use:

```
$app->get("/propertylist/", function () use ($app, $db) {
$app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
$req = $app->request();
$bed = $req->get('bed');
$bath = $req->get('bath');
$city = $req->get('city');
$zip = $req->get('zip');
if($bed ==''){$bed=0;}
if($bath ==''){$bath=0;}
if($zip ==''){
$properties = $db->rets_property_listing_mrmls_resi->limit(2500,0)->where("Bedrooms >= ?", $bed)->where("City LIKE ?", "%$city%")->where("BathsTotal >= ?", $bath);
}else{
$properties = $db->rets_property_listing_mrmls_resi->limit(2500,0)->where("Bedrooms >= ?", $bed)->where("ZipCode LIKE ?", "%$zip%")->where("BathsTotal >= ?", $bath);
}

$propertylist = array(); //Create variable type array

foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $propertylist[] = array(
        "MLSnumber" => $property["MLnumber"],
        "ListPrice" => number_format($property["ListPrice"]),
        "StreetNumber" => $property["StreetNumber"],
        "StreetName" => $property["StreetName"],
        "SqFt" => $property["SquareFootageStructure"],
        "PropertyDescription" => summaryMode($property["PropertyDescription"],15),
        "Bedrooms" => $property["Bedrooms"],
        "BathsTotal" => $property["BathsTotal"],
        "LO_Name" => $property["LO_Name"]
        );
}
echo json_encode($propertylist);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that version of PHP just changed the variables' scope, now it's more like you expect in other languages. If you define/create a variable in a block, it's not visible in the outer scope.

In your case, `$propertylist` is defined directly in the `foreach` block scope, hence it isn't visible to the rest of the code, causing the error.

As @Guilherme Nascimento suggested, you have to define it outside the loop.
That's said, in PHP is perfectly fine (but not recommended) to use a variable without instantiate it:

```
$var[] = 1;
// => array(1)
```